# How to get makefile to depend on any files inside a folder

Tags: makefile, latex

I have a simple `makefile` that I use to build some latex files. The syntax looks like this:

```
pdf: thesis.tex chapters/a.tex chapters/b.tex chapters/c.tex
    latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex thesis.tex

open:
    open thesis.pdf
```

The files inside `chapters` folder can increase further with `d.tex`, `e.tex` and may even contain subfolders `f\section1.tex`, `f\section2.tex` etc.

I manually add all the requried tex files inside my `thesis.tex` like this which is not a problem.

```
\input{chapters/a.tex}
\input{chapters/b.tex}
\input{chapters/c.tex}
\input{chapters/d.tex}
\input{chapters/e.tex}
```

1. How can I get make target `pdf` to depend upon any file changes inside chapters and its subdirectories?
2. How do I write inter task dependency in makefile. If target `open` depends upon target `pdf`, how do I write it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`open: pdf` will sort-of do what you want for your second question.

Though it would be better to not use the phony `pdf` target for this.

Instead have a `thesis.pdf:` target which depends on the right prerequisites and have both `pdf: thesis.pdf` and `open: thesis.pdf` targets.

For the first question you can either use something like:

```
SRCS := $(shell find chapters -name '*.tex')
```

or use [from here](http://blog.jgc.org/2011/07/gnu-make-recursive-wildcard-function.html):

```
rwildcard=$(strip $(foreach d,$(wildcard $1*),$(call rwildcard,$d/,$2) $(filter $(subst *,%,$2),$d)))

SRCS := $(call rwildcard,chapters,*.tex)
```

and then:

```
thesis.pdf: thesis.tex $(SRCS)
```

to use that variable as the prereq.

If you wanted to get even fancier you could write a script to pull out the actual filenames from the `\input{}` directives in `thesis.tex` and use that as your `SRCS` variable (but that's probably not worth the effort unless you know you will have other, unrelated, `.tex` files).

Comment: Works thanks. I'm used to Ruby's rake and Java's ant. So the difference is `target` in makefile actually means the destination file name?

Comment: Yes. You can use targets that don't mean filenames (they are called `.PHONY` targets) but they have slightly different semantics and behaviour in certain cases.

Comment: @EtanReisner Etan this is incorrect.  You cannot in a situation like this, depend on the results of some 'find', wildcard, or some such.  The problem is, if you were to delete one of the '.tex' files, but make no other changes, then the target would not rebuild, as it most definitely should! The correct and best solution, is to always explicitly list the files in thy makefile, and in addition to them, also depend thy target on the Makefile.  This way, to delete a file you must edit the Makefile, and target rebuilds.

Comment: @MarkGaleck As is generally the case you are correct. Though a stamp file with the contents of `SRCS` would also work to distinguish these deletion-only cases without triggering a build on unrelated `Makefile` changes.